# TimeScale Plugin Problem using Locust as a library, No INIT?

Tags: locust, timescaledb

I am using locust as a library and try to output statistics to TimeScaledb.
But when I investigated and try to pass command line arguments (which Timescale listeners.py initializes itself from) it seems to locust init event listeners are not triggered when using locust as a library. Is this the default behavior, are there any possible options to overcome this?

Here's what my code looks like,

```
# Built-in/Generic Imports
import json
import random
import time
import redis
import gevent
import os
import locust_plugins
from locust import User, task, tag
from locust import events
from locust.env import Environment
from locust.log import setup_logging
from locust.stats import stats_printer, stats_history
from argparse import Namespace



test_dict_cmd_args = Namespace()
test_dict_cmd_args.pghost = pg_host_env
test_dict_cmd_args.pguser = pg_user_env
test_dict_cmd_args.pgpassword = pg_password_env
test_dict_cmd_args.pgport = pg_port_env
test_dict_cmd_args.stop_timeout = 0
test_dict_cmd_args.timescale = 1



env = Environment(user_classes=[RedisLocust] events=events)

env.create_local_runner()
gevent.spawn(stats_printer(env.stats))

# start a greenlet that save current stats to history
gevent.spawn(stats_history, env.runner)

# start the test
env.runner.start(user_count=1, spawn_rate=5)

# in 60 seconds stop the runner
gevent.spawn_later(10, lambda: env.runner.quit())

# wait for the greenlets
env.runner.greenlet.join()
```

I also tried to pass parsed_options dict to environment which did not helped as well.

Here's what I tried for debuggings

locust_plugins> **init**.py

```
@events.init.add_listener
def on_locust_init(environment, **kwargs):
    print("INIT HAPPENED")
    if environment.parsed_options.timescale:
        global _timescale_added
        if not _timescale_added:
            Timescale(env=environment)
            _timescale_added = True
    options = environment.parsed_options
    print(options)
    print(type(options))
```

It seems this functions does not get triggered when run as a library.

I was expecting to use the locust-plugins when in library mode. Both passing a Namespace and trying to change in init hook did not work. I am trying to figure out a way to output to TimeScaledb when running locust as library.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try to fire the init event yourself. Currently it is fired by `main.py`, which isnt used at all when using locust as-a-library (this might be something we can fix in the future).

I modified/added the lines marked ###

```
env = Environment(user_classes=[RedisLocust] events=events)

runner = env.create_local_runner()                     ###
gevent.spawn(stats_printer(env.stats))

# start a greenlet that save current stats to history
gevent.spawn(stats_history, env.runner)

env.events.init.fire(environment=env, runner=runner)   ###

# start the test
env.runner.start(user_count=1, spawn_rate=5)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This fix worked for me. I am also trying to use locust as a library and faced similar issue while pushing metrics to timescale.

Comment: Greetings, thanks a lot for the answer, I see the init event being fired, @Sukhbir how did you pass the environment variables regarding timescale connection

Comment: yes I have passed pguser and pgpassword to locust

Comment: I get parsed_options set as None when I run locust as library therefore get no writes to TimeScaleDB, AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'timescale', 
On the other hand I can see it writing to assigned db to TimescaleDB by environment variables when I run with "locust -f "

Comment: I think the reason is that parser method which sets the environment:
@events.init_command_line_parser.add_listener
def add_checks_arguments(parser: configargparse.ArgumentParser):
does not also run when using locust as a library, I tried to use the same method Cyberwiz mentioned by trying env.events.init_command_line_parser.fire() which requires a parser to be passed tried to pass configargparse.ArgumentParser and it also failed.

Comment: @aemreg look at this stackoverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74370695/locust-how-to-pass-new-configuration-through-code-to-locust/74373577
I get it resolved through this. along with what cyberwiz answered on this page.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer @Sukhbir, I got it working following your question,
Adding before runner and fire,
parser = locust.argument_parser.get_parser()
p = parser.parse_args("--headless -f backend_test.py --timescale --pguser "+pg_user_env +" --pghost "+pg_host_env+" --pgdatabase "+ pg_database_env + " --pgpassword "+pg_password_env + " --pgport " + pg_port_env)
env = Environment(user_classes=[RedisLocust], events=events, parsed_options=p)