# Locust - How to pass new configuration through code to locust

Tags: python, load-testing, locust

I am trying to run locust as a library from python code and along with that I wanted to use [locust-plugins library](https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/tree/master/locust_plugins/dashboards). The main problem I am facing is that I am not able to find how to pass additional command line arguments from code to locust ? locust-plugins library is providing command line arguments like timescale and pguser. but I am not able to pass it to locust through code.

If I use locust as a command line tool, I can run it as following command:

locust --headless -f backend_test.py --host="" --timescale --pguser postgres

For running locust as a library, I followed this guide from official documentation: https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/use-as-lib.html

But [Environment](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html#environment-class) class does not take any additional arguments. I wanted to pass timescale and pguser argument to locust from code.
Any help or guidance is appreciated. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure anyone has done this before so it is kind of expected that you run in to some issues :)

What I would try is parsing a "fake" command line, and passing it to the Environment constructor.

You'll need locust-plugins 2.6.12 or later (I renamed the `add_arguments` method just now)

```
parser = locust.argument_parser.get_parser()
p = parser.parse_options("--headless -f backend_test.py --host="" --timescale --pguser postgres")
env = Environment(parsed_options=p, ...)
runner = env.create_local_runner() 
env.events.init.fire(environment=env, runner=runner)
```

Comment: I am getting following error with locust-plugins 2.6.12 version:-

File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/argparse.py", line 1601, in _handle_conflict_error
    raise ArgumentError(action, message % conflict_string)
argparse.ArgumentError: argument --check-rps: conflicting option string: --check-rps

Comment: Looks like options have already been added? Maybe `locust_plugins.add_arguments(parser)` is unnecessary. Try skipping that.

Comment: Now, It is giving error that parse_options method is not found in LocustArgumentParser class. "AttributeError: 'LocustArgumentParser' object has no attribute 'parse_options'. Did you mean: '_parse_optional'?"

After this I tried replacing that method with parse_args(). No error came but this is not pushing any metrics in grafana dashboard. Any idea ? 
I am running locust-compuse up in one terminal and running the python file for parsing args etc in another terminal.

Comment: parse_args is probably right. Can you try it without docker, preferably in a single process?

Comment: I updated the answer with what I think you ended up doing to get it working. Let me know if you did something else as well :)